# How to convert datatable to Excel using c#

Tags: excel, datatable, export-to-excel

Converting datatable to excel (xls or xlsx) using closed xml.
This will help you when you are provide download functionality to using.
and you are using sql server and provided data in excel to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Download closedxml from nuget.

```
using(XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook()) {  
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);  
            wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;  
            wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;  

            Response.Clear();  
            Response.Buffer = true;  
            Response.Charset = "";  
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";  
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= EmployeeReport.xlsx");  

            using(MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {  
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);  
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);  
                Response.Flush();  
                Response.End();  
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach, using [GemBox.Spreadsheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet):

```
ExcelFile ef = new ExcelFile();
ef.Styles.Normal.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignmentStyle.Center;
ef.Styles.Normal.Font.Weight = ExcelFont.BoldWeight;

ExcelWorksheet ws = ef.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
ws.InsertDataTable(dt);

ef.Save(Response, "EmployeeReport.xlsx");
```